# JSF application Deployment time function call

Tags: deployment, jsf

IN JSP i used to put things in bean's constructor which is in APPLCIATION scope, 
similarly 
i want to load a function upon deploy of application where i can put .

i tried putting in listener but @ that time i am not getting faces config 's injection .

so is there any way out ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tt sounds suspicious that the listener hadn't worked for you. It should've worked. What I assume has happened is that you expect your request-scoped beans to get their dependencies injected outside a request/response cycle. Well, this won't happen.

So you'd better do one of these:

- put the `@PostConstruct` annotation on every bean and initialize it.
- register a `ServletRequestListener` which gets triggered on each request

If you want a managed bean to initialize something application-wide (what is that something, btw):

1. Create a managed bean with scope `application`
2. Do your initialization in a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`

Btw, you have been wrong to put JSP initialization code in constructor. It should've been in the `init(..)` method. (and actually, shouldn't have been in a JSP at all)

Alternatively you can use a `PhaseListener` (in the `faces-config.xml`), where to lazily load tha application settings.

Comment: i need to do this in JSF 1.2 ,
this is not working with 1.2,

and i also want initilized context

Comment: yeah but it will break my arch,
i have to do this with JSF 1.2 only,
bean with application scope gets constructed when its first used.not at deployment time so i am not able to do this using your given 2 options

is there any thing like listner which listens bean initilization event

Comment: what would be the difference actually? Whether it's on deployment or on first access?

And as I said - the Servlet Listener is just fine. You are perhaps misusing it.

Comment: nop.. 
at deployment time i am not getting fully initilized context on which i need to call method..

Comment: what _exactly_ is not initialized?

Comment: which bean. in what scope. edit your question adding all the necessary details. I can't help if you remain so vague.